# Code::Blocks returns -10737741819 (0xC0000005) when executing nested loops

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I've been trying to use nested loops to insert integers into a two dimensional array in the following format:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10
>
> 2, 4 ,6 ,8 ,10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20
>
> 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24 ,27, 30
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> 10, 20 , 30 ,40 , 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100

I used the following code to generate the result:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int table[10][10];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            table[i][j] = (j * i);
            cout << table[i][j] << "\t"<< flush;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code runs successfully but gives an error in middle of executing: [image]

I'm currently using Code::Blocks + GNU GCC Compiler.
How can I solve the issue? Is it because of my code? or the compiler?

Comment: Array indexes in C++ start from 0.  So an array of size 10 has indexes [0..9]

Comment: Arrays are [0-indexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)

Comment: ***compiling successfully for me.*** Unfortunately Undefined Behavior sometimes appears to work correctly. `for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {` should be `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {`

Comment: `or the compiler`  It would be a joke of a compiler if it couldn't compile a toy program correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should start iterating from 0 (inclusive) to 10 (exclusive):

[[Try It Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p3PgKEsM5sQeMMIV)]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int table[10][10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            table[i][j] = ((j+1) * (i+1));
            cout << table[i][j] << "\t"<< flush;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: if you use C++17, you can use [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to avoid hard-coding the array size multiple times. (Alternatively, you can use some compiler specific macros.)

Comment: @MukeshA and according to which C/C++ standard does the OP's code result in defined behavior? The OP's code obviously compiles, but will result in undefined behavior since you will access an array out of bounds. And undefined behavior is undefined thus could result in literally anything including crashing and wiping your OS.

Comment: I actually tried it out and not only it changes the results, but also gives the same error: https://i.imgur.com/4RyVNB9.jpg

Comment: @RouzbehZarei I changed the output to generate your desired output. In Wandbox you can try different gcc and clang versions: it compiles and runs without crashing.

Comment: @RouzbehZarei ***but also gives the same error*** Your new picture (i.imgur.com/4RyVNB9.jpg)  shows no error. Return 0 means the program succeeded.

Comment: @drescherjm I actually uploaded wrong picture, and I just realized this is kind of random, sometimes a code runs pretty well and sometimes I receive (0xC0000005) error for the same code.

Comment: This code should work. Your original code had a bug that is explained in this answer and the comments on the question. I have no idea why your program would crash. If you are using `aVast` disable it.

Comment: @Matthias Thank you for your help. I just used C++ compiler and it ran both codes perfectly, I guess there's some kind of issue with GNU GCC Compiler which is the default for Code::Blocks.

Comment: ***I guess there's some kind of issue with GNU GCC Compiler which is the default for Code::Blocks*** It's possible but highly unlikely. I expect you will have a better chance of winning a raffle for a brand new sports car than a bug in your compiler causing this.

Comment: @drescherjm Some say it's because I starded 'i' and 'j' from 1 while I should have started from 0. I actually changed my code from (int i = 1; j < 11; ++j) to (int i = 0; j <= 10; ++j) and it still gives same error.

Comment: @RouzbehZarei I doubt that gcc is the culprit. If you know the version, you can [try it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p3PgKEsM5sQeMMIV).

Comment: ***I actually changed my code from (int i = 1; j < 11; ++j) to (int i = 0; j <= 10; ++j) and it still gives same error.*** That is a bug as well. It must be `(int i = 0; j < 10; ++j) ` The valid indices of an array of size 10 are `0 .. 9`. 10 or 11 (or any number greater than 9 or less than 0) are out of bounds.

Comment: @RouzbehZarei you had `(int j = 1; j <= 10; ++j)` not `(int j = 1; j < 11; ++j)`, and I have `(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)` not `(int j = 0; j <= 10; ++j)`. Don't start mixing `i` and `j`, and don't go out of bounds. (Just copy paste the code of this answer.)

Comment: @Matthias Yes I just realized this is the problem causing the program to crash. Thank u. Guess there's no other way except changing (i * j) to (i+1)*(j+1).

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah I just realized the issue and I guess the fact that the program crashes or not depends on the compiler and how they behave. Thank u.

Comment: ***I guess the fact that the program crashes or not depends on the compiler and how they behave*** Google for `Undefined Behavior`. This is exactly what is happening.